# How do I force the XSL to write this out with a closing tag?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have this **XSL** snippet:

```
     <xsl:if test="@BookmarkId">
        <a>
          <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('week', @BookmarkId)"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </a>
      </xsl:if>
```

The output is:

```
<a name="week1"/>
```

But in this instance I require it to be:

```
<a name="week1"></a>
```

How can I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XSL parsing is shortening script tag causing issues in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534525/xsl-parsing-is-shortening-script-tag-causing-issues-in-ie)

Comment: That did the trick. Well, it seems to be better for me inside my CHtmlView anyway because the anchor is behaving more elegantly. If I still open the XMl directly in IE and view the source, it still does not have the closing tag. But i don't mind. I think my issue is resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use this solution

```
 <xsl:if test="@BookmarkId">
    <a>
      <xsl:attribute name="name">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('week', @BookmarkId)"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <![CDATA[ ]]>
    </a>
  </xsl:if>
```

Comment: Yes, @Quentin directed me to this resolution. Thanks.